# Redirect all URLs from http to https (with 301 ) except for a few

Tags: linux, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, 301-redirect

I am trying to 301 redirect all URLs from `http://` to `https://`, using .htaccess. Some dynamically generated URLs should be excluded.

Example of some URLs I do **not** want to redirect:

```
example.com/tt.php?xxx (where xxx can be any number)
example.com/top/xxx/site/xxx (where xxx can be any number or characters)
```

Right now my .htaccess looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

How can I "exclude" my dynamic URLs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Right now my `.htaccess` looks like this:

If that is all you have in your `.htaccess` file then you can include some *exceptions* for the URLs you want to exclude *before* your existing rule that redirects.

For example:

```
# Prevent further processing if requesting a URL of the form
# example.com/tt.php?xxx (where xxx can be any number)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\d+$
RewriteRule ^tt\.php$ - [L]

# Prevent further processing if requesting a URL of the form
# example.com/top/xxx/site/xxx (where xxx can be any number or characters)
RewriteRule ^top/[^/]+/site/ - [L]
```

By placing the above "exceptions" *first* then any directives that follow (ie. the redirect) will be skipped.

---

**UPDATE:** If you had other directives in your `.htaccess` file that should still apply to these URLs then you can instead add additional conditions to your existing redirect rule instead.

For example:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]{3,6}\s/tt\.php\?\d+\sHTTP
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/top/[^/]+/site/

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Note that the first two conditions have a `!` prefix on the *CondPattern* in order to negate its meaning. So, the condition is only successful if the regex does *not* match.

Note that instead of using two directives (`RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule`) as I did in the first example to match against the URL `/tt.php?xxx` I combined this into a single rule and matched against `THE_REQUEST` - this is to simplify the logic in this one rule.

`THE_REQUEST` server variable holds the first line of the HTTP request.

Comment: I've updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer MrWhite! the first row worked perfectly but the second row: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^top/[^/]+/site/ did not work, it still gets 301 redirected to https

Comment: @Rogge Sorry, there needs to be a slash prefix on that regex, ie. `!^/top/[^/]+/site/` (different to the regex in the first example). I've updated my answer

Comment: You will need to make sure you've cleared your browser cache. (It can be easier to test with 302 temporary redirects for this reason.)

Comment: Thanks a lot MrWhite it works perfectly now! :)